# Prioritize real time msgs over batch msgs using Queues/MDBs

Tags: weblogic, priority-queue, batch-processing, message-driven-bean

In my application a specific service has a constant bandwidth (For e.g 100 transactions at a time ) , requests to the service arrive real-time as well as batch jobs (Queues). The real time requests doesnt have a uniform distribution. I need a way to make sure that real time jobs are processed first before the batch jobs and also make sure that at any time I don't exceed the threshold of the service.

Please evaluate the following approach.

Have 2 queues A - real time and B - Batch job. Have a thread pool of size = 100 (Service Threshold ) and let the 
thread pool first try to pick msgs from A if any else pick from B.

My application runs on Weblogic , I want to make use of MDBs instead of the thread pool but there is no way to make the MDBs listen to multiple Queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within JMS you can set a message priority which should be respected if possible.  This may be something simple to try.

Another option could be to set a JMS property on the message with the client and use a Message Selector on the MDB.  You could set MY_MESSAGE_TYPE=batch/rt and then have multiple MDB's deployed that are listening to the same queue but can be assigned to different work managers.  Keep in mind that Work Manager != Thread Pool.  You can also set a Request Class to ensure that if the batch pool is in use that the RT pool will not be starved for threads/CPU.

With this design I believe that if you have two MDB's, one with a message selector, messages that meet the selector criteria should be delivered to the MDB with that selector (RT) before an MDB with no selectors (BATCH).  This would be a fairly simple POC to do - set up a client that sends messages to the queue, some of which have the JMS property set to RT and others that do not have it set.

10.0 referece (which is still applicable): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_wls/self_tuned.html